# warning if allocating a structure on the stack

Tags: c, api, stack, abi

I'm changing an existing structure which is normally used on the stack, to one that cannot be used on the stack. During this transition phase, is there a way to notify users with a warning or a pragma not to allocate structure on the stack?

for example

```
struct mytype {
    int var;
}
struct mytype *newType_alloc() {
    return malloc(sizeof(mytype));
}
void main(void)
{
    struct mytype oldWay;
    struct mytype *newWay = newType_alloc();
}
```

I would like that gcc or clang would warn me that I created `oldWay` on the stack without using its allocator (`newType_alloc()`).

The rationale is that adding fields to `newType` would break ABI and this needs to be changed.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `without using its allocator.`?

Comment: i mean that the only way for creating a `struct mytype` should be via newType_alloc().

Comment: Do the users need access to the members of the structure?

Comment: can you show us all of the code?

Comment: What compiler? What platform? Why can't the type be used "on the stack"?

Comment: @LearningCODE: That's a bad request. We try to discourage, not encourage, people from dumping "all of their code".

Comment: possibly linux with gcc/clang. It can't be used on the stack because adding fields to it would break ABI and this needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like removing the struct definition from the user interface (i.e. the user header file) would do what you want in terms of alerting the user that declaring the struct in the "old way" will not compile.

That said, you're currently implementing breaking API changes. Therefore, anyone updating to your new API should be made aware of the changes.

Comment: yeah that can't be done, as the `struct mytype` is widely used. I'm aware this is an API break, that's why I'm trying to alert the user.